# Why is GitHub Desktop not letting me interact with it?

Tags: github-for-windows

It's been a while since I've used my GitHub Desktop, on Windows 10, but when I decided to try and open it again I ran into a weird issue: GitHub Desktop wouldn't let me click on anything except the minimize, maximize, and close.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall it, but that did not work.

Before the Login screen come up on the client, their is a screen that flashes before it that has the text:

> Drop to clone long-repository-name

With some other words that are all on the same line overlapping each other.

I have tried looking online for anyone with a similar issue, but all I could find were authentication issues.

If anyone knows of a fix, or if I have clearly done something wrong please let me know.

[Here is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui7pC.png)

Comment: I would speculate this is an input problem. In particular, the "Drop to clone" suggest that Github for Windows thinks you are dragging the URL of a repository. I believe this question is only tangentially related to programming (it is about a tool some programmers use), and thus it is better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). I suggest asking there, and do not forget to mention the version of Github for Windows you have. I am voting to close.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion I will move this to SuperUser.